# Flatlist Selects all for Favourites, instead of One

Tags: react-native, rest, react-native-flatlist

The heart icon on my Flatlist in which i try to do Add to Toggle hearts, Save the Data to AsyncStorage does not work as expected. It instead, selects everything on the flat list instead of selecting just one. Why is this so?

I have the Code like this

```
  componentWillMount()
  {
    const { movie_desc, UrlImage, favorite } = this.props;
    this.setState({ movie_desc, UrlImage, favorite });
  }

  componentWillUpdate() {
    LayoutAnimation.easeInEaseOut();
}
```

And in the main render() Function, I have this

```
  render() 
  {
    const { movie_desc, UrlImage, favorite } = this.state;
        return (
            <View style={styles.MainContainer}>
            <FlatList
            data={ this.state.dataSource }
            ItemSeparatorComponent = {this.FlatListItemSeparator}
            renderItem={({item}) => 
                <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                    <Icon
                        name={favorite ? 'heart' : 'heart-o'}
                        color={favorite ? '#F44336' : 'rgb(50, 50, 50)'}
                        size={30}
                        style={{ marginBottom: 10, marginTop: 20 }}
                        onPress={() => this.setState({ favorite: !favorite })}
                    />
                    <Image source = {{ uri: item.url_image}} style={styles.imageView} />
                    <Text style={styles.textView} >{item.movie_description}</Text>
                </View>
                }
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
            />
            </View>
        );
  }
}
```

Instead it just selects everything like this

[image]

Full code is looking Like this

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {  StyleSheet, Platform, View, ActivityIndicator, FlatList, Text, Image, Alert, LayoutAnimation, YellowBox , Button , AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';

export default class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        UrlImage : '',
        movie_desc : '',
        favourite : false
    };
  }

  GetItem (movie_description) {
    Alert.alert(movie_description);
    }

    SaveData = () =>
    {
        const movieData = {
            UrlImage : this.state.UrlImage,
            movie_desc : this.state.movie_desc
        };

        AsyncStorage.setItem('movie',JSON.stringify(movieData));
    }

  ShowMovies = () =>{
    return fetch('https://uncoiled-crust.000webhostapp.com/api/movies_db.php')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
      this.setState({
        isLoading: false,
        dataSource: responseJson
      }, function() {
        // In this block you can do something with new state.
      });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
  }
  
  componentWillMount()
  {
    const { movie_desc, UrlImage, favorite } = this.props;
    this.setState({ movie_desc, UrlImage, favorite });
  }

  SelectItem(movie_desc){
      Alert.alert(movie_desc);
  }

  componentWillUpdate() {
    LayoutAnimation.easeInEaseOut();
}


  componentDidMount(){
      this.ShowMovies();
  }

  FlatListItemSeparator = () => {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          height: .5,
          width: "100%",
          backgroundColor: "#000",
        }}
      />
    );
  }
  

  render() 
  {
    const { movie_desc, UrlImage, favorite } = this.state;
        return (
            <View style={styles.MainContainer}>
            <FlatList
            data={ this.state.dataSource }
            ItemSeparatorComponent = {this.FlatListItemSeparator}
            renderItem={({item}) => 
                <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                    <Icon
                        name={favorite ? 'heart' : 'heart-o'}
                        color={favorite ? '#F44336' : 'rgb(50, 50, 50)'}
                        size={30}
                        style={{ marginBottom: 10, marginTop: 20 }}
                        onPress={() => this.SelectItem({ favorite: !favorite })}
                    />
                    <Image source = {{ uri: item.url_image}} style={styles.imageView} />
                    <Text style={styles.textView} >{item.movie_description}</Text>
                </View>
                }
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
            />
            </View>
        );
  }
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    MainContainer :{
     
        justifyContent: 'center',
        flex:1,
        margin: 5,
        marginTop: (Platform.OS === 'ios') ? 20 : 0,
    },
    imageView: {
        width: '50%',
        height: 350 ,
        margin: 7,
        borderRadius : 7
     
    },
    textView: {
        width:'50%', 
        textAlignVertical:'center',
        padding:10,
        color: '#000'
     
    }
    });
```

**Edits**

I did this As edits

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {  StyleSheet, Platform, View, ActivityIndicator, FlatList, Text, Image, Alert, LayoutAnimation, YellowBox , Button , AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';

export default class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        UrlImage : '',
        movie_desc : '',
        favourite : false
    };
  }

  GetItem (movie_description) {
    Alert.alert(movie_description);
    }

    SaveData = () =>
    {
        const movieData = {
            UrlImage : this.state.UrlImage,
            movie_desc : this.state.movie_desc
        };

        AsyncStorage.setItem('movie',JSON.stringify(movieData));
    }

  ShowMovies = () =>{
    return fetch('https://uncoiled-crust.000webhostapp.com/api/movies_db.php')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
        const result = responseJson.map((value, index) => ({
            ...value,
            isFavourite: 0
        }))
        
      this.setState({
        isLoading: false,
        dataSource: responseJson
      }, function() {
        // In this block you can do something with new state.
      });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
  }
  
  componentWillMount()
  {
    const { movie_desc, UrlImage, favorite } = this.props;
    this.setState({ movie_desc, UrlImage, favorite });
  }

  SelectItem(movie_desc){
      Alert.alert(movie_desc);
  }

  componentWillUpdate() {
    LayoutAnimation.easeInEaseOut();
}


  componentDidMount(){
      this.ShowMovies();
  }

  FlatListItemSeparator = () => {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          height: .5,
          width: "100%",
          backgroundColor: "#000",
        }}
      />
    );
  }

  changeisFavorite = (item, index) => {
    let arr = [...this.state.dataSource]
    arr[index].isFavorite = item.isFavorite == 1 ? 0:1;
    this.setState({ dataSource: arr });
}
  

  render() 
  {
    const { movie_desc, UrlImage, favorite } = this.state;
        return (
            <View style={styles.MainContainer}>
            <FlatList
            data={ this.state.dataSource }
            ItemSeparatorComponent = {this.FlatListItemSeparator}
            renderItem={({item,index}) => 
                <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                    <Icon
                        name={item.isFavourite == 1 ? 'heart' : 'heart-o'}
                        color={item.isFavourite == 1 ? '#F44336' : 'rgb(50, 50, 50)'}
                        size={30}
                        style={{ marginBottom: 10, marginTop: 20 }}
                        onPress={() => this.changeisFavorite(item, index)}
                    />
                    <Image source = {{ uri: item.url_image}} style={styles.imageView} />
                    <Text style={styles.textView} >{item.movie_description}</Text>
                </View>
                }
            />
            </View>
        );
  }
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    MainContainer :{
     
        justifyContent: 'center',
        flex:1,
        margin: 5,
        marginTop: (Platform.OS === 'ios') ? 20 : 0,
    },
    imageView: {
        width: '50%',
        height: 350 ,
        margin: 7,
        borderRadius : 7
     
    },
    textView: {
        width:'50%', 
        textAlignVertical:'center',
        padding:10,
        color: '#000'
     
    }
    });
```

Its just static. Does not do anything.

Comment: Put favorite field in every item, and change favorite in the selected item. But you create one field favorite for all items.

Comment: @VasylNahuliak, Pls show me. I am a bit lost here. This is first time working on stuff like this

Comment: see good example on video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OVklR0t_SH0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ShowMovies function add isFavorite status or add the status field in the database

```
const result = responseJson.map((value, index) => ({
                ...value,
                isFavourite: 0
            }))

 this.setState({
        isLoading: false,
        dataSource: result
      }
```

In Flatlist render item use isFavorite sataus

```
   renderItem={({item, index}) => 
                <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                    <Icon
                        name={item.isFavorite == 1 ? 'heart' : 'heart-o'}
                        color={item.isFavorite == 1  ? '#F44336' : 'rgb(50, 50, 50)'}
                        size={30}
                        style={{ marginBottom: 10, marginTop: 20 }}
                        onPress={() => this.changeisFavorite(item, index)}
                    />
                    <Image source = {{ uri: item.url_image}} style={styles.imageView} />
                    <Text style={styles.textView} >{item.movie_description}</Text>
                </View>
                }
```

OnClick Favorite Icon

```
changeisFavorite = (item, index) => {
        let arr = [...this.state.dataSource]
        arr[index].isFavorite = item.isFavorite == 1 ? 0:1;
        this.setState({ dataSource: arr });
    }
```

Comment: Its static. Icon does not change. Please See Edits ..

Comment: it is working just changes the  'dataSource: responseJson' to 'dataSource: result' in ShowMovies function and correct the spelling of isFavourite in changeisFavorite function.

Comment: Oh many thanks , works fine now . Now how Do i make it save to AsyncStorage. Just wanted to call that SaveData that should be fine , right, or there needs some adjustments too?

Comment: It will work with AsyncStorage but with only saveData, the changes in the API movies list will be not changed in the app.